# Is it possible to connect php code with mysql database without using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, port, mysql-workbench

I have been trying to fix my phpMyAdmin, because it has clashing ports with MySql Workbench, I have tried the various methods on the internet and nothing seems to work. From trying to switch the port of phpMyAdmin to port 3307 to editing the config.ini file, but nothing works, so i have decided to find out if there is a way of skipping the whole phpMyAdmin process and just code php and connect it to my webpages.

---

Extract

---

In case anybody knows how to fix this, I'm open to anymore suggestions.

```
9:33:07 AM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
9:33:07 AM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MYSQL57"!
9:33:07 AM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
9:33:07 AM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
9:33:07 AM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
9:33:07 AM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
9:33:07 AM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
```

Comment: *phpmyadmin* is just a website, which can also connect to mysql. The answer is **yes**, you can connect to mysql without phpmyadmin.

Comment: For the error, seems like mySQL server is already started on the port 3306.

Comment: I would suggest that the problem here is your SQL Server and not PhpMyAdmin. So you should start with the error your SQL Server logs.

Comment: As @JeremyF. comments, have you installed MySql twice?  How did you install, how do you run?  PhpMyAdmin is just a MySql database client.

Comment: @JeremyF Yes I had already determined that, i also tried to stop the mysql process that was running in the background, still did not work.

Comment: @Progrock, I already installed mysql community before hand, I did not think, they would clash.

Answer (score -1):

First, the port you use (3306) is already used by an other process. You can end this process for example.

Yes, you can connect to mysql via any other tool (try to install mysql workbench for example).